# Cannot find libHalide.so to build

Tags: halide

I'd like to build the Halide [tutorials](https://halide-lang.org/tutorials/tutorial_lesson_02_input_image.html) on mac.

The instruction says:

```
// On os x:
// g++ lesson_02*.cpp -g -I <path/to/Halide.h> -I <path/to/tools/halide_image_io.h> -L <path/to/libHalide.so> -lHalide `libpng-config --cflags --ldflags` -ljpeg -o lesson_02 -std=c++17
// DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=<path/to/libHalide.dylib> ./lesson_02
```

From the release of Halide, I can locate Halide.h and libHalide.dylib but not libHalide.so.

Where do I find it?

Example:

```
find . -name 'Halide.h'
./include/Halide.h
```

but looking for the .so file returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions were originally written for Linux systems. On macOS, shared libraries use the `.dylib` extension, not `.so`, so this amounts to a typo in the tutorial.

---

That said, I would recommend using CMake instead...

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(tutorial)

find_package(Halide REQUIRED)

add_executable(lesson02 lesson02.cpp)
target_link_libraries(lesson02 PRIVATE Halide::Halide)
```

This build is portable across Windows, macOS, and Linux.

Comment: Trying with .dylib instead: 

`g++ lesson_01*.cpp -g -I <path>/Halide-13.0.2-x86-64-osx/include/Halide.h -L <path>/Halide-13.0.2-x86-64-osx/lib/libHalide.dylib -lHalide -o lesson_01 -std=c++17`

Fails with:
`Halide-13.0.2-x86-64-osx/lib/libHalide.dylib' is not a directory` 

I also tried using the make provided in the halide source code:
```
 make tutorial_lesson_01_basics
make: *** No rule to make target `/Users/kelvinhanma/Halide/src/../LICENSE.txt', needed by `include/Halide.h'.  Stop.
```

Comment: The Makefile exists to support certain internal developer workflows... Halide users should use the CMake build. The argument to `-L` should be the directory containing `libHalide.dylib`